# How to check if there is a file input using pipe

Tags: c++

how can I know the command line is:
./main
or:
./main < filename

Answer (score 2):

Generally you shouldn't pay attention or care, but if you really need to, you can use something like

```
if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
   // getting input from console
else
   // probably getting input from a file.
```

Neither `isatty` or `fileno` is a standardized part of C proper, but both are included in POSIX (if memory serves) and available on most non-POSIX systems as well (e.g., on Windows, though MS considers these names deprecated, and advises useing `_isatty` and `_fileno` respectively).

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Unix (POSIX) system, you can use `fstat()` on the standard input file descriptor.  You can then analyze the file type - up to a point.  It is not clear that you can reliably and portably detect a pipe input, but you can detect files and character devices (probably a terminal, unless it is `/dev/null`) reliably.